# Question about pinning version of Debian package

Tags: apt

I added a pinned configuration like below:

```
Package: cinder*
Pin: version 2:13.0.7*
Pin-Priority: 1001
```

The version of the package installed is 2:13.0.5-0ubuntu1~cloud0.
When I execute the command `apt list --upgradable`, we can see that the version 2.13.0.8 will be installed.

```
cinder-common/bionic-updates 2:13.0.8-0ubuntu1~cloud0 all [upgradable from: 2:13.0.5-0ubuntu1~cloud0]
```

In fact the version 2.13.0.7 is no longer available in the repository. However I don't understand why the system wants to upgrade to version 2.13.0.8; could someone explain?

Answer (score 1):

A pin defines a priority for packages matching the pin: in your case, packages whose name starts with `cinder`, and whose version starts with 2.13.0.7. Packages which don’t match the pin, which includes `cinder` packages with another version, follow any other matching pin, or the default priorities.

Since 2.13.0.7 is no longer in the archives, and isn’t currently installed, there’s no artifact matching the pin, and no artifact given priority 1001. 2.13.0.8 presumably gets the default priority of 500 or 990, and is a legitimate candidate for upgrade; nothing has a higher priority so it ends up being *the* candidate.